# How to save data in text file that is scrape from website?

Tags: python

```
import urllib.request
import re    
text_file = open("scrape.txt","w")
html = urllib.request.urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping")
text = html.read()
pattern = re.compile(b'<span dir="auto">(.+?)</span>')
key = re.findall(pattern, text)
text_file.write(key)
```

And its return this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>      in 
>       text_file.write(key)
>   TypeError: must be str, not list

Comment: It doesn't works. now the error occur is : Traceback (most recent call last): text_file.write(found) TypeError: must be str, not bytes.How should i resolve this??

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
key = re.findall(pattern, text)
```

is returning a list, where in this line:

```
text_file.write(key)
```

you want to save a string.

So what you (probably) want is:

```
for found in key:
  text_file.write(found)
```